# Custom validation constraint using a validator exposed as a service

Tags: symfony

I have a custom validator exposed as a service (as it requires other sevices as dependencies). I defined it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

   <services>
      <service id="validator.unique.available_email_validator" 
               class="Nourdine\BasicBundle\Validator\Constraints\AvailableEmailValidator">
         <argument type="service" id="signup_manager" />
         <tag name="validator.constraint_validator" alias="available_email_validator" />
      </service>   
   </services>

</container>
```

Trouble is the whole thing does not work, error being:

```
Class 'available_email_validator' not found in /home/nourdine/development/symf-app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 67
```

As a matter of fact the the validator does not appear among available services when doing:

```
console container:debug
```

So I suspect the problem is with the service not being exposed correctly. Solve that and I solve the validation process blowing up.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

As it said in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies):

```
As mentioned above, Symfony2 will automatically look for a class named after the constraint, with Validator appended. If your constraint validator is defined as a service, it's important that you override the validatedBy() method to return the alias used when defining your service, otherwise Symfony2 won't use the constraint validator service, and will instantiate the class instead, without any dependencies injected.
```

If your class can't be found, you probably forgot to renamme the string returned by validatedBy() method by your alias (in your validator class):

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'available_email_validator';
}
```

Comment: actually no! have a look yourself: http://code.google.com/p/symf-test/source/browse/trunk/src/Nourdine/BasicBundle/Validator/Constraints/AvailableEmail.php. Creazy isn't it?

Comment: Ok did you put the service xml code in the file Nourdine\BasicBundle\Resources\config\services.xml, and aslo are you sure in your app/config/routing.yml that your NourdineBasicBundle is injected ?

Comment: "hell yes" to the first question. It is in there and kicking! Look: http://code.google.com/p/symf-test/source/browse/trunk/src/Nourdine/BasicBundle/Resources/config/services.xml

I have no idea what you mean with the second question though :(

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue when defining it as a service.